# Convert date inside map function of render in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

The following code is inside return of render function

```
this.props.investment.selectedInvestor.rounds.map((item,index)=>{
   if(item.type.toLowerCase()==this.state.securityType.toLowerCase())
   {
      return(
        <tr onClick={()=>this.showRoundDetails(true,item)}>
        <td>
          <strong>{item.round_name}</strong><br/>
          <span>{item.close_date}</span>
          </td>
        <td>{item.security_type}</td>
        <td>{item.sharing_plan}</td>
        <td>{item.investments[0].status}</td>
        <td>{item.rate}</td>
        <td>{item.frequency}</td>
        <td>{item.investments[0].current_amount}</td>
        </tr>
        )  
    }                             
  }
```

I want to convert `{item.close_date}` to another format i.e use this function `toLocaleDateString()`
I tried declaring another variable outside return and then convert the date but still could not solve it

Comment: whats the format of `item.close_date`? Are you OK with using external libraries?

Comment: if `item.close_data` is a `Date object` then you can use that method directly like this: `<span>{item.close_date.toLocaleDateString()}</span>`

Comment: {item.close_date} is a string

Comment: Can you show example of it?

Comment: 2017-05-10T11:01:50.569Z is the value of that object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`{item.close_date}` is a string (that contains the date) as you mentioned in comment, to use `toLocaleDateString()` method first you need to convert that string into `date object` by using `new Date()`, after that you can use any date method on that.

Use this:

```
<span>{ (new Date(item.close_date)).toLocaleDateString() }</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript date method:

```
<span>{ (new Date(item.close_date)).toLocaleDateString() }</span>
```

```js
var d =  new Date("2017-05-10T11:01:50.569Z");
console.log(d.getDay(), d.getMonth(), d.toLocaleDateString())
```

Using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) library

```
<span> 
    { 
       moment("2017-05-10T11:01:50.569Z", "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSS").format("hh:mm a") 
    }
</span>
```

```js
var d = moment("2017-05-10T11:01:50.569Z", "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSS")
console.log(d.format("hh:mm a"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I prefer momentjs because I can parse and get date in any format.